# iOS NSAttributedString emoji transparency/alpha

Tags: ios, transparency, alpha, nsattributedstring, emoji

I'm using an UITextView and want some parts of the text to be transparent.

I'm currently using an NSAttributedString with NSForegroundColorAttribute having the color with the desired transparency.

It works for regular characters but not for emoticons.
Is it possible to set the emoticons transparent in a UITextView? If so, how?

Note: I'm looking to support iOS6 or above.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I ended up doing was adding a view over each emoticon with the background color of the textview and alpha value inverted (if I wanted character to have 30%transparency the view would have alpha 0.7) to fake the emoticon transparency

Comment: Got it. Thanks, i'll see about considering other options like that.